# add items into session

Tags: php, session, yii

I'm very new to sessions... How do I add items? My items do get added but it keeps replacing my existing item with another item with the same number of quantity.

So I add item A quantity 3, then add item B quantity 1. It shows, item B quantity 3. Item A disappears.

I have:

```
$addItem = array(
    "product_id" => $id,
    "quantity" => $quantity,
    );
    Yii::app()->session['cart']= $addItem;
```

then i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604592/storing-array-in-sessions), doesn't seem to be adding anything?:

```
public function actionBasket($id)
    {
        $session=new CHttpSession;
        $session->open();

        $quantity = 1;

        if (!isset(Yii::app()->session['carts'])) {
                Yii::app()->session['carts'] = 
                array(
                "product_id" => $id,
                "quantity" => $quantity);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $products = Yii::app()->session['carts'];
                $products[] = array(
                        "product_id" => $id,
                        "quantity" => $quantity);
                Yii::app()->session['carts'] = $products;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might well find that you are overwriting the session there.

perhaps

```
Yii::app()->session['cart']['item'];
```

Comment: don't think i have it correct, but I get a null array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Yii::app()->session['carts'][] = 
   array(
      "product_id" => $id,
      "quantity" => $quantity
   );
```

This will append a new product onto the session each time rather than overwriting it. You can get to the items using:

```
foreach (Yii->app()->session['carts'] as $item) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: i got an error "Indirect modification of overloaded element of CDbHttpSession has no effect"